# Jest: How to expect two arrays to be disjoint

Tags: jestjs

I need to assert that an array does not contain *any* of the elements of a second array. In other words, I need to assert that two arrays are [disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets).

I have tried the following two approaches. To be clear, I expect the following tests to **fail**.

```js
it('expects arrays to be disjoint', () => {
    expect(['a', 'b', 'c']).not.toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(['c', 'd']));
});
```

and

```js
it('expects arrays to be disjoint', () => {
    expect(['a', 'b', 'c']).toEqual(expect.not.arrayContaining(['c', 'd']));
});
```

These tests **pass**, even though the element `'c'` is common to both arrays.

How can I write this test in such a way that the test will fail if the arrays aren't disjoint?

Below is the best that I've been able to do. Is there a more idiomatic way do to it with Jest?

```js
it('expects arrays to be disjoint', () => {
    const intersection = ['a', 'b', 'c'].filter((value) => ['c', 'd'].includes(value));
    expect(intersection.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: Try: `['a', 'b', 'c'].some(e => ['c', 'd'].includes(e))`

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks fine and *idiomatic enough* as well as `.some()` suggested by @jarmod.

There are no *native* support for such a check for a reason: ordering *matters* for array(unlike `Set` recently introduced as part of ECMAScript). So we way more often need to respect order than ignore it.

Since both `filter + includes` and `some` run M*N checks, for really long arrays we may convert them both(with M + N operations) into `Set` or `Object`(using some property as a key) and then check for intersection by `in` or `Set.has()`(that would need min(M, N) operations). So it would be O(N) instead of O(N^2). But in real world we typically mock some short data for unit tests, until it's something integration testing, so it could be probably be better for readability to has check with `some` since it's shorter, more clear => more readable.

Answer (score 0):

With the '[jest-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended#toincludeanymembersmembers)' package the following would be an even shorter version:

```
expect(['a', 'b', 'c']).not.toIncludeAnyMembers(['c', 'd']);
```